# implementing scd type 2 as a generalized stored procedure in azure data warehouse for all dimensions?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, data-warehouse, scd

I am new to azure and I am working on Azure data warehouse. I have loaded few dimensions and staging tables. I want to implement SCD type 2 as a generalised procedure for all the updates with hashbytes. As we know, ADW doesnt support merge, I am trying to implement this with normal insert and update statements with a startdate and enddate column. But the schemas of the dimension table are not exactly the same as those in the staging table, there are few columns that are not considered.

Initially i thought i will pass in the staging and dimension table as parameters, and fetch schema from sys objects, create a temp table, load necessary column from stage and do a hashbyte and compare hashbyte from temp and dimension, but is this a good approach?

PS: Also one more problem, is the sometimes the column names are mapped different, like branchid as branch_id. How do i fetch columns for these. Note that this is just one case, and this could be the case in many tables as well.